# Generic type with keyof not accepted

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function which is called either with a record or an interface, but using a generic type does not work:

```
interface Iface {
  add?: string;
  create?: string;
}

// TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.
function f<T extends Iface|Record<string, string>>(key:keyof T, obj:T){
  obj[key] = 'something';
}

function fi(key: keyof Iface, obj: Iface) {
  obj[key] = 'something';
}

function fr(key: string, obj: Record<string, string>) {
  obj[key] = 'something';
}
```

typescript complains about function f. Why?

-- Edit --

What's wrong with this?

```
function f3<T extends Record<string, string>>(key:string, obj:T){
  obj[key] = 'something'; 
}
```

Comment: There is not really type-safe. See this example: https://tsplay.dev/Wokn9W

Comment: Added f3 in code, what's wrong with this?

Comment: Sorry I should have elaborated more: Check out this [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1ADyw). `obj` has a symbol key of type number. When we call the function using `obj` and its symbol key, we overwrite the `number` with a `string`. The type of `obj` has not changed though and still asumes that the symbol is of type number. This can lead to a runtime error which can be seen when you run the code in the Playground. So the error you are getting is correctly preventing this scenario.

Comment: Code in playground has changed now. Write an answer please. I think the error is because of the bug in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47357